# What are the classification methods available for face recognition watchlist screening?

Tags: computer-vision

My intention is to develop a method that only able to recognize a target among the non-target (unknown people) groups. **What algorithm/method can I go through** to build this type of classifier. It is like building a object detector? Where the detector, as an example is train to only detect particular object (no matter what the object looks like). Should I look into machine learning algorithm; genetic algorithm, neural network or evolutionary algorithm? However the problem is, the condition of my work only allow one still image (in frontal face view) of the target.

Comment: Please try to explain your question a bit more. What have you tried? What don't you understand?  What is the application? This question, as asked, is very unclear so we don't know what sort of answer to give.

Comment: Further to @PeterK. 's comment and since the revision popped up on my review queue as well, can I please ask you to expand a little bit on your question. The way it is phrased now is too broad. Portrait face recognition is a relatively easy classification task . Can you please provide a little bit more information about the problem to focus the question?

Comment: I try to look at the classification task for open set recognition. As an example, I had enrolled five people in the system, and I want the system only recognize the enrolled people and reject other unknown people which are not in the system database.